# tabela de notas de alunos

Tags: javascript

Ola, Bom dia, preciso realizar uma atividade "Escreva um documento HTML que simula uma tela de lançamento de notas em um sistema acadêmico.
Fiz assim, porém não estou conseguindo resolver a coluna de resultado...alguém poderia me ajudar..

```
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <title>Prototipo Sistema Academico</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/bootstrap.min.css'>
        <script src='js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
        <script>
        function calcula_media(i)
        {
            var N1=document.getElementsByName("n1")[i].value;
            var N2=document.getElementsByName("n2")[i].value;
            var media=document.getElementsByName("media");
            var calculo=(parseFloat(N1)+parseFloat(N2))/2;
            var result=document.getElementsByName("resultado");
            document.getElementsByName("resultado").innerHTML+="aprovado";
            if(calculo >=7)
            {
                media[i].innerHTML="<div class='text-success'>"+calculo+"</div>";


            }
            else
            {
                media[i].innerHTML+="<div class='text-danger'>"+calculo+"</div>";
            }

        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

            <div class="container">
              <h2>Hover Rows</h2>
              <p>The .table-hover class enables a hover state on table rows:</p>
              <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Estudante</th>
                    <th>N1</th>
                    <th>N2</th>
                    <th>Média</th>
                    <th>Resultado Final</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Ana da Silva</td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0"name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(0)"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0"name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(0)"></td>
                    <td><div name="media"> </div></td>
                    <td><div name="resultado">-- </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>Beatriz da Silva Leite</td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0"name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(1)"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0"name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(1)"></td>
                        <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                        <td><div name="media"> </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>Breno Silva da Silva</td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0"name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(2)"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0"name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(2)"></td>
                        <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                        <td><div name="media"> </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Carlos da Silva</td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0"name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(3)"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0"name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(3)"></td>
                    <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                    <td><div name="media"> </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Caroline Soares</td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0"name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(4)"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0"name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(4)"></td>
                    <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                    <td><div name="media"> </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Debora Machado</td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0"name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(5)"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0"name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(5)"></td>
                    <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                    <td><div name="media"> </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Daniel Guerrera</td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0"name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(6)"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0"name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(6)"></td>
                    <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                    <td><div name="media"> </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Fabiana Molina</td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0"name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(7)"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0"name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(7)"></td>
                    <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                    <td><div name="media"> </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Helena Garcia</td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0"name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(8)"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0"name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(8)"></td>
                    <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                    <td><div name="media"> </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Galvão Bueno </td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0"name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(9)"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0"name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(9)"></td>
                    <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                    <td><div name="media"> </div></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Que calculos deve fazer par o resultado? A média eu sei, e o resultado?

Comment: O que deveria aparecer em resultado ?

Comment: aprovado e reprovado dependendo da média

Answer (score 2):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- explicação do problema conforme você postou colega

            Prototipo Sistema Academico:
                function calcula_media(i){ 
                    var N1 = document.getElementsByName("n1")[i].value;
                    var N2 = document.getElementsByName("n2")[i].value;
                    var media = document.getElementsByName("media");
                    var calculo = ( parseFloat(N1) + parseFloat(N2) )/2;
                    var result = document.getElementsByName("resultado");

                    document.getElementsByName("resultado").innerHTML += "aprovado";
                    if(calculo >=7){
                        media[i].innerHTML = "+calculo+";
                    }
                }
        -->
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Hover Rows</h2>
            <p>The .table-hover class enables a hover state on table rows:</p>
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Estudante</th>
                        <th>N1</th>
                        <th>N2</th>
                        <th>Média</th>
                        <th>Resultado Final</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ana da Silva</td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(0)"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(0)"></td>
                        <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                        <td><div name="resultado">-- </div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Beatriz da Silva Leite</td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(1)"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(1)"></td>
                        <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                        <td><div name="resultado">-- </div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Breno Silva da Silva</td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(2)"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(2)"></td>
                        <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                        <td><div name="resultado">-- </div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Carlos da Silva</td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(3)"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(3)"></td>
                        <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                        <td><div name="resultado">-- </div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Caroline Soares</td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(4)"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(4)"></td>
                        <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                        <td><div name="resultado">-- </div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Debora Machado</td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(5)"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(5)"></td>
                        <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                        <td><div name="resultado">-- </div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Daniel Guerrera</td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(6)"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(6)"></td>
                        <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                        <td><div name="resultado">-- </div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fabiana Molina</td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(7)"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(7)"></td>
                        <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                        <td><div name="resultado">-- </div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Helena Garcia</td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(8)"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(8)"></td>
                        <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                        <td><div name="resultado">-- </div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Galvão Bueno </td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(9)"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(9)"></td>
                        <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                        <td><div name="resultado">-- </div></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <script>

            /*
            * Erros encontrados:
            *   - atributos colados(max="10.0"name="n1") correto(max="10.0" name="n1")
            *   - você não colocou o indice correto para media e resultado
            *   - a ordem dos objetos na sua função não estavam corretas
            *   - o indice é utilizado para recuperar o objeto em questão após não se faz necessário colocar na variável como você fez no result
            */

            function calcula_media(i){
                var N1 = document.getElementsByName("n1")[i].value;
                var N2 = document.getElementsByName("n2")[i].value;
                var calculo = ( parseFloat(N1) + parseFloat(N2) )/2;
                var media = document.getElementsByName("media")[i];
                media.innerHTML = calculo;
                var result = document.getElementsByName("resultado")[i];
                if(calculo >= 0.7){
                    result.innerHTML = "Aprovado";
                }else{
                    result.innerHTML = "Reprovado";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Estou vendo que você está utilizando para pegar os valores o método getElementsByName. Tente utilizar o método getElementById, que sempre retornará um valor apenas. Modifiquei o seu Html para comportar com Id ao invés de Name. Lembrando que fiz apenas com dois alunos, apenas insira mais alunos como a lógica abaixo:

```
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <title>Prototipo Sistema Academico</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <script src='js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script>
    function calcula_media(i)
    {
        var n1 = document.getElementById("n1_aluno_" + i).value;
        var n2 = document.getElementById("n2_aluno_" + i).value;
        var media = document.getElementById("media_aluno_" + i);
        var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado_aluno_" + i);

        var calculo = (parseFloat(n1) + parseFloat(n2)) / 2;

        if(calculo >= 7)
        {
            media.innerHTML = "<div class='text-success'>" + calculo + "</div>";
            resultado.innerHTML = "Aprovado";
        }
        else
        {
            media.innerHTML = "<div class='text-danger'>" + calculo + "</div>";
            resultado.innerHTML = "Reprovado";
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

        <div class="container">
          <h2>Hover Rows</h2>
          <p>The .table-hover class enables a hover state on table rows:</p>
          <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Estudante</th>
                <th>N1</th>
                <th>N2</th>
                <th>Média</th>
                <th>Resultado Final</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Ana da Silva</td>
                <td><input id="n1_aluno_0" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(0)"></td>
                <td><input id="n2_aluno_0" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(0)"></td>
                <td><div id="media_aluno_0"> </div></td>
                <td><div id="resultado_aluno_0">-- </div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Beatriz da Silva Leite</td>
                <td><input id="n1_aluno_1" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(1)"></td>
                <td><input id="n2_aluno_1" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(1)"></td>
                <td><div id="media_aluno_1"> </div></td>
                <td><div id="resultado_aluno_1">-- </div></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Isso resolve seu problema:

```js
            function calcula_media(i){
                var n1 = document.getElementsByName("n1")[i].value;
                var n2 = document.getElementsByName("n2")[i].value;
                var media = document.getElementsByName("media");
                var resultado = document.getElementsByName("resultado");

                var calculo = (parseFloat(n1) + parseFloat(n2)) / 2;

                if(calculo >= 7)
                {
                    media[i].innerHTML = "<div class='text-success'>" + calculo + "</div>";
                    resultado[i].innerHTML = "<div class='text-success'>Aprovado</div>";
                }
                else
                {
                    media[i].innerHTML = "<div class='text-danger'>" + calculo + "</div>";
                    resultado[i].innerHTML = "<div class='text-danger'>Reprovado</div>";
                }
            }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
              <h2>Hover Rows</h2>
              <p>The .table-hover class enables a hover state on table rows:</p>
              <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Estudante</th>
                    <th>N1</th>
                    <th>N2</th>
                    <th>Média</th>
                    <th>Resultado Final</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Ana da Silva</td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(0)"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(0)"></td>
                    <td><div name="media"> </div></td>
                    <td><div name="resultado">-- </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>Beatriz da Silva Leite</td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(1)"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(1)"></td>
                        <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                        <td><div name="resultado"> </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>Breno Silva da Silva</td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(2)"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(2)"></td>
                        <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                        <td><div name="resultado"> </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Carlos da Silva</td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(3)"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(3)"></td>
                    <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                    <td><div name="resultado"> </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Caroline Soares</td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(4)"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(4)"></td>
                    <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                    <td><div name="media"> </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Debora Machado</td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(5)"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(5)"></td>
                    <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                    <td><div name="media"> </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Daniel Guerrera</td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(6)"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(6)"></td>
                    <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                    <td><div name="media"> </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Fabiana Molina</td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(7)"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(7)"></td>
                    <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                    <td><div name="media"> </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Helena Garcia</td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(8)"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(8)"></td>
                    <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                    <td><div name="media"> </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Galvão Bueno </td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n1" onchange="calcula_media(9)"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" name="n2" onchange="calcula_media(9)"></td>
                    <td><div name="media">0,0</div></td>
                    <td><div name="media"> </div></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
```